# Uber Android Rides SDK SSO AccessToken

Tags: android, uber-api

I'm trying to implement Uber Ride Request in my app.

The problem is with initial LoginManager and receiving access token.

What I've done so far

- Registered app and got client id.
- Added android debug.keystore's App signature on dashboard
- Uber app installed and logged in with my uber account(it's also my developer account)
- Handled onActivityResult and LoginCallback is also being called.
- But fails always with UNKNOWN error.

  ```
  SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
          .setClientId(BuildConfig.UBER_CLIENT_ID)
          .setEnvironment(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX : SessionConfiguration.Environment.PRODUCTION)
          .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.REQUEST))
          .build();

  UberSdk.initialize(config);
  ```

When the access token is null, I'm requesting to login as follows

```
loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager, loginCallback);
loginManager.login(MainActivity.this);
```

And loginCallback in MainActivity is below

```
private LoginCallback loginCallback = new LoginCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLoginCancel() {
        // User canceled login
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
        // Error occurred during login
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
        // Successful login!  The AccessToken will have already been saved.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {

    }
};
```

But, always `onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error)` is being called with `AuthenticationError.UNKNOWN` string as a result on loginCallback.
Please, help me out. I'm missing anything.

Comment: Can you provide more detail or share the exact request / response and exception error message?

Comment: @DustinWhittle I've added the callback and updated the question. Can you please look into it. Will be very much thankful. Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: @DustinWhittle Do I need to provide more details... Shall I give you access to my bitbucket project? I'm badly in need of this. Plz

Comment: Yes, please share the underlying request/response. It is not possible to tell the error without more details.